# Search entire workbook including hidden sheets, and return the sheet name of where it was found. Do not want to unhide all worksheets first

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Working on creating a single location of all my notes. Need to be able to hide all sheets and search through them for a cell value.

Have not located a code that will work, or a formula. I am open to either.

The sheets are not formatted the same and the search could be anywhere on any sheet.

[image]

Comment: VBA is probably ideal here. Look up a `For Each` Worksheet loop with each iteration using `Range.Find` maybe. There isn't near enough info in this question for anyone to actually provide you with a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Sub SubSearch()
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksTarget As Worksheet
    Dim StrPO As String
    Dim BlnFoundResult As Boolean
    
    'Setting.
    StrPO = "A3921"
    
    'Covering each worksheet.
    For Each WksTarget In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Searching for a match.
        If Not WksTarget.Cells.Find(What:=StrPO, _
                          After:=WksTarget.Cells(1, 1), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False _
                         ) Is Nothing _
        Then
            
            'Reporting the found match.
            MsgBox StrPO & " found in " & WksTarget.Name, vbOKOnly, "Found"
            
            'Setting BlnFoundResult as true.
            BlnFoundResult = True
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'If BlnFoundResult is still false, it's reported that no match has been found.
    If BlnFoundResult = False Then
        MsgBox StrPO & " has not been found", vbOKOnly, "Not found"
    End If
    
End Sub
```

Here you have basically the same subroutine turned into a function that you can use in a formula:

```
Function FunSearch(StrWhat As String) As String
    
    'Declarations.
    Dim WksTarget As Worksheet
    Dim StrPO As String
    Dim StrMarker As String
    
    'Setting.
    StrPO = StrWhat
    StrMarker = " | "
    
    'Covering each worksheet.
    For Each WksTarget In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        
        'Searching for a match.
        If Not WksTarget.Cells.Find(What:=StrPO, _
                          After:=WksTarget.Cells(1, 1), _
                          LookIn:=xlValues, _
                          LookAt:=xlPart, _
                          SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                          SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                          MatchCase:=False, _
                          SearchFormat:=False _
                         ) Is Nothing _
        Then
            
            'Reporting the found match.
            FunSearch = FunSearch & WksTarget.Name & StrMarker
            
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'If FunSearch is still empty, it's reported that no match has been found. Otherwise the result is trimmed of the last StrMarker.
    If FunSearch = "" Then
        FunSearch = "No match found"
    Else
        FunSearch = Left(FunSearch, Len(FunSearch) - Len(StrMarker))
    End If


End Function
```